# Drag items without triggering blur or mouseleave events

Tags: javascript, html

I perform some actions on `blur` or `mouseleave`, but initiating dragging of items in the container triggers these.

```js
window.addEventListener(`blur`, () => {
  console.log(`blur triggered`)
})

document.documentElement.addEventListener(`mouseleave`, () => {
  console.log(`mouseleave triggered`)
})

document.documentElement.addEventListener(`mouseenter`, () => {
  console.log(`mouseenter triggered`)
})
```

```css
.item {
  background-color: blue;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div draggable=true class='item'>Item 1</div>
  <div draggable=true class='item'>Item 2</div>
  <div draggable=true class='item'>Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Basically I want none of these events triggering except when I normally move the cursor out of the window (and click in the case of blur). Ideally if there's a way to have this without using state variables since those make the logic more complex and might be prone to failure.

Comment: Set a variable when a drag begins (and clear it when it ends), and then you can check whether or not you are dragging inside your other events.

Comment: You could create a flag and set it to true on [`dragstart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragstart_event) and to false on [`dragend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dragend_event). Using that flag you can decide, if you want to perform the action or not.

Comment: Is it not possible without the variable?